# Get MongoDB server time from the C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

1. how do I get MongoDB current server time from the C# driver?
2. In case I have multiple shards and replica set, does monogo allow their time to be out synch?
3. As for case 2, if the several servers' times are out of sync, which server time will I be getting?

Comment: ATM MongoDB does not use server time for stuff like dates and that, instead it uses UTC only

Comment: I understand the need for getting the server time:  if you timestamp transactions or record metadata, you want to get your times from a single definitive source:  not for client machines that are not under your control, and which may-or-may-not be synchronized with a time server.

Comment: @Sammaye ATM means ?

Comment: @Alex75 sorry - "At The Momernt"

Comment: @Alex75 Sorry again, I think this answer is heavily out of date, I remember reading in some change notes that MongoDB can have a set timezone from the server now

Comment: Thanks fro the clarification on ATM (I was thinking "Atlas T.. M.." or "Appear To Me") :-). Anyway I think I have the same doubt similar to the OP ones, because I need to "compare" (which one came first) 2 records that potentially came from 2 instances of the same services. I was wondering to trust the database date (common to both) to have a trustable datetime to compare. But... Our Mongo cluster have 3 nodes and our service are synched with NTP so... maybe the services time is more accurate than the database one.

Comment: @Alex75 hmm yeah, though if DB is in UTC all the time (check that one, I haven't used MongoDB in over a year) then it will be accurate so long as the the MongoDB binary has the same definition of UTC, which could be a problem since that definition would come form the server even if you cannot access server time directly, hmm, I guess the benefit of using NTP is that you don't need to care about server config ever having weird flaws that could compromise your DB integrity, but if you did have that then sharding etc etc would also be hit, so that's really unlikely

Comment: @Alex75 ah Asya actually states this below, she gives the answer (as I was thinking) that servers should be synced via NTP and MongoDB then takes definition from that since to do otherwise could easily create drift in internal timestamp (that you cannot access) causing replication/sharding problems, so NTP should really be used "behind the scenes" if not directly in the DB definitely

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad idea to run any cluster without synchronizing the clocks across all of them via NTP or something equivalent.

In a sharded cluster with replica sets for shards the number of problems you may run into if your clocks drift out of sync are numerous and difficult to diagnose.

Use `ntpd` and as an added advantage you can then use current time from your C# app server without worrying about it being different than the server time.

Comment: This may not be accurate enough to timestamp and/or sequence records which may be coming in from multiple client machines.    It would be much cleaner design-wise to be able to ask the primary server in a cluster for its current time.

Comment: by definition, ntpd will be accurate enough - if configured and run correctly.  Since mongoDB is usually deployed as a cluster there is no concept of a single "server" - is it primary? what if this is a sharded cluster? Should this feature stop working?